# How to store and access JSON data for a site?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jsonp

I'm buiding an HTML/jQuery site where almost all the content comes from remote JSON data. I'm having trouble coming up with a good way to store and access the data in the future (scope-wise).

Currently, I've written a jQuery plugin that gets the JSONP data when the site loads. But I have other functions and jQuery plugins that need to access this data.

Where should this data be stored so other functions and plugins can access it?

Should it be a global variable?

If it matters, this site will only run on the iPad and the back-end of the site is in Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you investigate HTML5 persistant storage which is supported on Safari and Mobile Safari as a SQL Lite DB. If you decide not to go down that route I would opt for $().data() over a global variable in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the info. $().data() appears to attach the data to a DOM element. Would you suggest I just attach it to the document or body?

Comment: Given that you'll be potentially accessing this data from anywhere in the page, I'd probably attach to document, but I don't think it makes a great deal of difference. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a manageable amount of JSON data you can access it through global variables. Preferably just one or two global objects with nested properties.

Developing a web page is not like developing a library I think a few globals are acceptable

Answer (score 1):

To store data between requests, you can use [HTML5 Storage API](http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/). Otherwise just pass around the variable (reference) holding the data.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo has it.

If you do not have the constraint of using jquery, then maybe you can investigate it.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/dojostorage-offline-access-and-permanent-client-side-storage

Alternately, you could also probably just store it in an array that other plugins / functions can access it.